# Change the UITableViewCell layout on selection

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, uitableview

I have a `tableview` where the cell uses the `right detail layout`. What I want to do now is when a user selects a cell. I should add an image to that cell?

Any suggestions how I should implement this?

Kind regards

Comment: could u please post the code

Comment: create delegate method and call that method when cell is clicked

Answer (score 1):

You can do this in `-tableView:didSelectForRowAtIndexPath:` that is when the user selects you can create an image view and add it

Answer (score 0):

You have not given any detail about where your Images are retained.

If your Images are at **Cache Directory** ,then you should write your `-didSelectRowAtIndexPath` like this...

```
NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSCachesDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
UIImage *image = [[UIImage alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:[[paths lastObject] stringByAppendingPathComponent:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Image-%d.png",indexPath.row]]];
yourImageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:image];
[cell addSubView;yourImageView];
```

If you are downloading Images from **Server** ,then your code should look like this :

```
NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://yourURL.com"]]]; 
UIImage *image = [[UIImage alloc] initWithData:data];
yourImageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:image];
[cell addSubView;yourImageView];
```

GoodLuck ...!!!

Answer (score 0):

Try implementing this

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    [tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:YES];

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    cell.imageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"imageName"];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create your subclass of UITableViewCell.
Then implement method -touchBegin, and doing you need